# How can I style these filter buttons along a line neatly?

Tags: css

I'm trying to duplicate a certain way to display my post filter buttons -- in a row, with a bottom border, with the border changing color and size when item is selected.

Right now my line appears to not line up between active and not active elements. I also need to understand how to do a transition between the two.

My current display (scroll down to "colombia posts":
https://theslowroad.org/category/destinations/south-america/colombia/

My desired results (produced by a plugin):
https://theslowroad.org/27895-2/

My current CSS:

```
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 21px;
font-weight: 600;
background: #ffffff;
font-family: lato;
line-height: 30px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;

border-bottom: solid #c8c8c8;
border-bottom-width: 0.5px;
transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s, 0.3s, 0.3s;
```

and on hover/active:

```
background: #ffffff;
color: #bf593a;
border-bottom:  solid #bf593a;
border-bottom-width: 4px;
```

Can anyone lend a hand? I'm very new at this!

Edited to add: 
It appears that the issue with the grey and orange borders not lining up depending on screen size. ??

Comment: On chrome it appears to be working, though it grows down from the bottom rather than out from the center.

Comment: Not sure I'm noticing the issue either, though I would advise to stick to whole pixel values and your transition-duration appear innocuous.

Comment: How can I get it to grow down from the top? What I am seeing is that the top of the colored bar doesn't line up with the top of the grey bar.

Comment: This only seems to happen at certain screen sizes (e.g., my full screen on a 13" laptop)??